# R Connect server: Push Notifcations

Tags: r

I'm wondering if it is possible to have a rshiny app that is hosted on my ubuntu connect server and that is able to send notifcations. However, I'm not looking for notifcations that get only displayed in the browser window. I want to have s.th. like a Desktop notifacation that is always displayed, no matter with a minimized or maximized browser window.

I found this repository. When I build a shiny app on my local windows Rstudio instance,

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h2("Push notification"),
  use_push(),
  actionButton("show", "Show notification"),
  textInput("title", "Text to display", "Hello world :)")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$show, {
    push(title = input$title)
  })
  
}
```

shinyApp(ui, server)
I get what I want:

[image]

However, running the example from the respository and a hosted Rshiny application on my connect server does not work. I do not receive any notifcation.

So, maybe me knowledge about web development is limited, so is even this technically achievable?
If yes, are you familiar with any other option to achieve my goal?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like you want your shiny app in a browser window to produce an OS-level notification while the app is open, is that right? That is often a little difficult to do due to sandboxing and security measures. Two options: [`shiny::showNotification`](https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/notifications/) is an in-app (in-browser-windows) notification-like width; use an external API to provide push notifications (e.g., pushbullet, many others), not restricted to shiny apps (I use PB a lot), requires user to be using that push service.